# Configuring the context path of a web app outside the WAR's WEB-INF directory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, war, wildfly

I am trying to deploy my web app as a WAR file to WildFly 9.

I can specify the context path of the web app by renaming the WAR file in the `deployments` directory or by specifying the context in `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` inside the WAR file.

Is there a way to specify the context path **outside** the `WEB-INF` directory of the WAR file? This way it would be possible to change the context path after packaging the WAR.

Comment: Well, the name of the war is kind of outside the `WEB-INF` directory, isn't it?

Comment: Yep, that's one possible thing to do, but I'm looking for some sort of configuration file that allows me to do this.

Comment: Configuration file isn't possible, but you can use different deployment ways to specify the context path, see the answers from Steve C and mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the context path at deployment time by using the CLI to perform the deployment.

```
[steve@mylaptop wildfly-9.0.0.Final]$ bin/jboss-cli.sh 
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] connect
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] deploy /path/to/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war --runtime-name=foo.war
```

This will result in your application being available at /foo

Use

```
deploy --help
```

for more information.

Comment: It's not possible to map the war to / this way, is it?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this via [WildFly Maven Plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/) as part of your CI job or similar.

We are using following command to deploy the war file to another context root:

```
org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:deploy-only
    -Dwildfly.deployment.filename=app.war 
    -Dwildfly.deployment.runtime.name=appcontext.war
```

The app will be deployed under **/appcontext**.

Note, you should remove the **context-root** from your *jboss-web.xml* otherwise this value will win always.

Answer (score 2):

There is the possibility to change context root of war application in runtime using [CLI console](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Management+Clients) Command Line Interface in Wildfly. It's possible with command [deployment-overlay](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Deployment+Overlays), in this way:

`deployment-overlay add --name=myAppOverlay \
  --content=/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml=/myFiles/new-jboss-web.xml \
  --deployments=myApp.war --redeploy-affected`

This command forces Wildfly to load the content of file `new-jboss-web.xml` into the internal Wildfly cache and use it (during every deployment of myApp.war) as the replacement of `/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` file of your war web-archive. As you already know, context of web application could be therefore defined in `new-jboss-web.xml` in following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>myNewPathToApp</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Besides `add` action, `deployment-overlay` CLI command has also [other actions](https://github.com/PayU/jboss-as/blob/master/cli/src/main/resources/help/deployment-overlay.txt) in order to manipulate with deployment overlays (e.g. remove overlay, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The context root for a web application is determined in three different ways:

- If it's deployed as part of an EAR, the context root is specified in the `application.xml` file of the EAR.
- If it's deployed as a standalone WAR, the context root can be specified in the `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml`.
- If no context root is specified, the context root will be the name of the WAR file.

I don't know a fourth option.

See also the official documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch06.html

Comment: your documentation link is nearly ten years out of date, particularly as the question is tagged with `wildfly`.